# Selenium test fails with java

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I use Selenium with cucumber in Java and when trying to do that :

```
WebElement MyAccountLink = driver.findElement(By.className("btn-outlined-white_medium_block"));
MyAccountLink.click();
```

I got this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"btn-outlined-white_medium_block"}
```

How can i solve it ?
Thanks.

Comment: You have a space in the class name before `_block`.

Comment: Sorry i corrected it and now i have : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"btn-outlined-white_medium_block"}

Comment: Try to find with `id` or `name`

Comment: Try to get xpath or Id of the Webelement.
Find xpath using firepath or inspect element in browser

Comment: Add relevant `html` code

Comment: This error can come due to multiple reasons. The HTML will help us in giving the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 'XPath' or 'cssSelector' instead of 'className', because it doesn't matters which locator you are using. you need to find the element and do automation on that element.

```
WebElement MyAccountLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("right click on element and copy xpath and paste it here"));
MyAccountLink.click();
```

Hope XPath will work in any case.

Comment: @A.Java If my answer solved your query, then you can click on the green tick mark on the left side. thank you.